# Distance limited flood fill BFS (Breadth First Search)

Tags: c++, path-finding

I'm trying to find if a certain area is reachable in a limited number of moves on a map using a flood fill BFS algorithm but I can’t get the implementation right . Here is a test map

```
int32_t map[MHEIGHT][MWIDTH] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
};
```

Where `-1` implies the region is inaccessible and `1` is the starting position/path.

This is what I think the algorithm is supposed to do your first node is the starting position, in my case it's where my map is [y,x]==1 and push this into your que. You then iterate through each element of your que. Then find the neighbors for each element, then you check each neighbor if it's accessible or its visited. And if it's not visited, you append it to the visited list and lastly append it to your list of reachable tiles.

```
vector<struct Coord> floodfillreachable(struct Coord& start, int32_t moves) {
    queue<struct Coord> q;
    
    vector<struct Coord> visited;
    
    q.push(start);
 
    while (q.size() > 0 && moves > 0) {
        struct Coord c = q.front();
        q.pop();
        vector <struct Coord> n = getneighbors(c);
        for (struct Coord& element : n){
            if (!isblocked(element)) {
                if (!contains(visited, element)) {
                    visited.push_back(element);
                    q.push(element);
                }
            }
        }
        --moves; // one iteration of moves completed
    }
        
    return visited;
}
```

Of course this could be completely wrong because my implementing gives me really odd results.
Full code

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using std::queue;
using std::vector;
using std::find;


#define MWIDTH 9
#define MHEIGHT 9

struct Coord{
    int32_t m;
    int32_t n;
};

int32_t map[MHEIGHT][MWIDTH] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
};

bool inbounds(int32_t m, int32_t n) {
    return (m >= 0 && m < MHEIGHT && n >= 0 && n < MWIDTH);
}

bool isblocked(struct Coord& k) {
    if (map[k.m][k.n] == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool contains(vector<struct Coord>& v, const struct Coord& k) {
    if(std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [k](const struct Coord& c){
        return c.m==k.m && c.n==k.n;
    }) != v.end()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


vector <struct Coord> getneighbors(struct Coord& k) {
    vector <struct Coord> neighbors;
    if (inbounds(k.m - 1, k.n)) {
        neighbors.push_back({(k.m-1),k.n});
    }
    if (inbounds(k.m,k.n - 1)) {
        neighbors.push_back({k.m,(k.n-1)});
    }
    if (inbounds(k.m + 1, k.n)) {
        neighbors.push_back({(k.m + 1),k.n});
    }
    if (inbounds(k.m, k.n + 1)) {
        neighbors.push_back({k.m, (k.n + 1)});
    }
    return neighbors;
}

vector<struct Coord> floodfillreachable(struct Coord& start, int32_t moves) {
    queue<struct Coord> q;
    
    vector<struct Coord> visited;
    
    q.push(start);
 
    while (q.size() > 0 && moves > 0) {
        struct Coord c = q.front();
        q.pop();
        vector <struct Coord> n = getneighbors(c);
        for (struct Coord& element : n){
            if (!isblocked(element)) {
                if (!contains(visited, element)) {
                    visited.push_back(element);
                    q.push(element);
                }
            }
        }
        --moves; // one iteration of moves completed
    }
        
    return visited;
}

void printmap(){
    for(int32_t m = 0; m < MHEIGHT; ++m){
        for(int32_t n = 0; n < MWIDTH; ++n){
            if(map[m][n]==1){
                std::cout << "*";
            }else if(map[m][n]==0){
                std::cout << "-";
            }else{
                std::cout << "@";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    Coord start = {3,3};
    vector <struct Coord> flooded = floodfillreachable(start, 2);
    for (struct Coord& k : flooded){
        map[k.m][k.n] = 1;
    }
    
    printmap();
    return 0;
}
```

But that's not correct at all since it flooded the whole map except the inaccessible tiles.

Expected result:

```
 ---------
 ---*-----
 --***----
 --@*@----
 --**@----
 ---*-----
 ---------
 ---------
 ---------
```

Produced result

```
---------
---*-----
--***----
--@*@----
---*@----
---------
---------
---------
---------
```

Comment: why is the result wrong?

Comment: @QingchuanZhang Because the distance between [3,3] and [8,8] is greater than 2 especially since I have inacessible tiles in the way.

Comment: @kayla Starting from coords {3,3}, it should flood fill it's neighbouring coords which contains 1 only, right?

Comment: @SureshMangs Correct, it should fill the x number of moves allowed with 1. The -1 represents the blocked tiles. From {3,3} it should present all available tiles within 2 moves.

Comment: @Kayla The size of the flooded.size() is equal to 75, the loop for(int32_t k = 1 ; k <= moves;++k) is wrong, we only need to make 'x' number of moves.

Comment: @SureshMangs Isn't `k<=moves` implying x number of moves? How do I fix this loop?

Comment: `for(int32_t k = 1 ; k <= moves;++k){` and then `while (q.size() > 0) {` - won't this mean that only the first `for` iteration gets to do any work?

Comment: Also, this seems too simplistic for what you want to accomplish: what if, say, UP, RIGHT, DOWN is considered before just RIGHT? - you'll have marked the tile as 'visited' with the longer path, so the shorter alternative is never tried.

Comment: @kayla check the answer, is this what you are required to do?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Longer or shorter here is irrelevant. Since I'm not looking for the shortest path. Rather, a simple way to check if a patch is accessible within x moves.

Comment: @Kayla where did you mention there is a limit on the number of moves?

Comment: @QingchuanZhang in the title “With move count” and the code takes a moves argument

Comment: @Kayla You should definitely describe the whole problem at the very beginning for others to help.

Answer (score 0):

The loop `for(int32_t k = 1 ; k <= moves;++k)` is wrong because we only want to make 'k' moves.

Let's say we want to make only 2 moves.

So according to the loop,
when k = 1, we will find all the coordinates which can be visited, but while visiting the coordinates we are not checking if we already made k moves.

So that's why all 0's in the map changes to 1's if there is a path to visit them.

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using std::queue;
using std::vector;
using std::find;


#define MWIDTH 9
#define MHEIGHT 9

struct Coord{
    int32_t m;
    int32_t n;
};

int32_t map[MHEIGHT][MWIDTH] = {
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
};

bool inbounds(int32_t m, int32_t n) {
    return (m >= 0 && m < MHEIGHT && n >= 0 && n < MWIDTH);
}

bool isblocked(struct Coord& k) {
    if (map[k.m][k.n] == -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool contains(vector<struct Coord>& v, const struct Coord& k) {
    if(std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [k](const struct Coord& c){
        return c.m==k.m && c.n==k.n;
    }) != v.end()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


vector <struct Coord> getneighbors(struct Coord& k) {
    vector <struct Coord> neighbors;
    if (inbounds(k.m - 1, k.n)) {
        neighbors.push_back({(k.m-1),k.n});
    }
    if (inbounds(k.m,k.n - 1)) {
        neighbors.push_back({k.m,(k.n-1)});
    }
    if (inbounds(k.m + 1, k.n)) {
        neighbors.push_back({(k.m + 1),k.n});
    }
    if (inbounds(k.m, k.n + 1)) {
        neighbors.push_back({k.m, (k.n + 1)});
    }
    return neighbors;
}

vector<struct Coord> floodfillreachable(struct Coord& start, int32_t moves) {
    queue<struct Coord> q;
    
    vector<struct Coord> visited;
    
    q.push(start);
    visited.push_back(start);
 
   while (moves > 0) {
         int size = q.size();
         while (size--) {
            struct Coord c = q.front();
            q.pop();
            vector <struct Coord> n = getneighbors(c);
            for (struct Coord& element : n){
                if (!isblocked(element)) {
                    if (!contains(visited, element)) {
                        visited.push_back(element);
                        q.push(element);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        moves--;
   }
        
    return visited;
}

void printmap(){
    for(int32_t m = 0; m < MHEIGHT; ++m){
        for(int32_t n = 0; n < MWIDTH; ++n){
            if(map[m][n]==1){
                std::cout << "*";
            }else if(map[m][n]==0){
                std::cout << "-";
            }else{
                std::cout << "@";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    Coord start = {3,3};
    vector <struct Coord> flooded = floodfillreachable(start, 2);
    for (struct Coord& k : flooded){
        map[k.m][k.n] = 1;
    }
    
    printmap();
    return 0;
}


/* output -

---------
---*-----
--***----
--@*@----
--**@----
---*-----
---------
---------
---------

*/
```

Comment: It's still not entirely accurate. It's close though. See my edits to the map and the code.

Comment: @Kayla edited the code, now the result is equal to the expected result.